# Sort function doesn't work on objects array IE 10

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am trying to sort objects array per "date" property.
This works fine in chrome, but in IE doesn't (PSB example 1).

I have tried sorting simple dates array and it works fine(example 2), only when the array is made of objects it doesn't.

Any idea why?

**example 1 - doesn't work:**

```
let objectsArr = [
  { dd: { name: 'l', address: 'dd' }, ww: { age: 15, city: 'BB' }, date: '12/03/2025' },
  { dd: { name: 'l', address: 'dd' }, ww: { age: 15, city: 'BB' }, date: '12/05/2025' },
  { dd: { name: 'l', address: 'dd' }, ww: { age: 15, city: 'BB' }, date: '12/03/2025' },
  { dd: { name: 'l', address: 'dd' }, ww: { age: 15, city: 'BB' }, date: '12/03/2015' },
  { dd: { name: 'l', address: 'dd' }, ww: { age: 15, city: 'BB' }, date: '10/03/2025' },
  { dd: { name: 'l', address: 'dd' }, ww: { age: 15, city: 'BB' }, date: '12/03/2029' },
  { dd: { name: 'l', address: 'dd' }, ww: { age: 15, city: 'BB' }, date: '12/03/2025' },
  { dd: { name: 'l', address: 'dd' }, ww: { age: 15, city: 'BB' }, date: '12/03/2005' },
];
objectsArr = objectsArr.sort(function (a, b) {
  return Date.parse(a.date) - Date.parse(b.date);
});
```

**example 2 - works OK:**

```
let datesArr = [
  '12/03/2025',
  '12/03/2021',
  '12/03/2020',
  '12/03/2021',
  '12/03/2019',
  '12/03/2023',
  '12/03/2011',
  '12/03/2016',
];
datesArr = datesArr.sort(function (a, b) {
  return Date.parse(a) - Date.parse(b);
});
```

Comment: keep in mind `Date.parse()` is implementation specific, you may want to write a more explicit date parsing method

Comment: I don't have access to a copy of IE10, but if I run your code examples in IE11 in IE10 emulation mode, both give the same error (`Expected `;`).  This appears to be because IE10 (or IE11 in IE10 emulation mode at least) doesn't support `let`.  Do you get the same error if you replace `let` with `var`?

Comment: the dates between the 2 examples are not the same

Comment: Chris Jackson, Microsoft's worldwide lead for cybersecurity explain that : "IE is not a browser, so stop using it"

Comment: I would check in IE and Chrome what is the result of `objectsArr.map(function(a) { return Date.parse(a.date); })` The date parser may work differently in IE because of some bug.

Comment: If its related to the Date.parse then why same code works ok on simple strings array?.Also I have tried different methods of date comparing (e.g. moment) and still didn't work on the objects array.